# Assign different url to diferent users

Tags: node.js, url, web-applications, url-routing

Am trying to create a web app with nodejs and this app will have a different profile for different users.
when a user sign up from **"www.site.com/signup"**, it should create a personal url for user e.g **"user_name.site.com"**

Comment: Please see "[ask]", "[Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648)" and all their linked pages.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is called a subdomain. Subdomains are not handled at the application level. You need to add an A record in your DNS for every subdomain. Usually this is done using the API provided by your domain provider (or wherever your nameservers are located). Then, you'll need to proxy each subdomain to your application using some other web server like Apache or nginx.

The solution depends on:

- Who your domain provider is.
- What web server you're using (if any). Apache, nginx, etc.
- The OS of the server.
- And probably a lot more depending on your specific use-case.

Essentially what you're looking for isn't quite straightforward, and will probably involve a ton of work to get right and stable. There's many ways you can do this and it really depends on the rest of your technology stack. Not much of this actually has anything to do with node.js.